# Как реализовать hover на кластере балуна яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как сделать `hover` на кластере балуна яндекс-карт?
Делаю следующее, но не работает, как это исправить?

```
<script> 
    //в whereMap - содержится айдишник карты код как его выбераю не прилогаю 
    whereMap.geoObjects.events.add('mouseenter', function (e) {
        var geoObject = e.get('target'),
            position = e.get('globalPixels'),
            balloon = geoObject.balloon;
            balloon.open(position);
            balloon.events.add('click', function () {
            balloon.open();
    });
</script>
```